# React Native : All tab bar icons are not showing

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am implementing three tab  but it is showing only two when I implement tabbaricon. When i remove the tabbaricon  now again it is showing three icon. I am using a functional component to render at tabbaricon.

I tried to debug but not able to understand where i am doing wrong.

```
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import AccountScreen from "../screens/AccountScreen";
import ListingEditScreen from "../screens/ListingEditScreen";
import Listingscreen from "../screens/Listingscreen";
import FeedNavigator from "./FeedNavigator";
import AccountNavigator from "./AccountNavigator";
import NewListingButton from "./NewListingButton";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Feed"
        component={FeedNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" size={size} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="ListingEdit"
        component={ListingEditScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarButton: () => <NewListingButton />,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="plus-circle"
              size={size}
              color={color}
              options={{}}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Account"
        component={AccountNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" size={size} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: Do your resolved this? Cause I get this as well, sometimes is showing in iOS, but android it cant show.. with no error at all